# Helper variables in a PHP library

Tags: php

I'm writing a very simple library (just a few functions, really), and I don't want to pollute the global space. E.g. my library is:

```
function helper () { ... }
function interesting () {
  ...
  helper();
  ...
}
```

I want `interesting()` to be visible when loading the file with `include`, but not `helper()`.

It seems to me that it's not possible (there's no such thing as a local scope in PHP), unless I use a class with private variables, or a namespace, but both solutions feel like overkills to me in this case. So, what is the recommended way to avoid polluting the global space?

Comment: Do you mean like having a different include file for helper?

Comment: No, everything is in the same file, but `helper()` should somehow be invisible, like a private variable in a class.

Comment: why it would be an overkill to just create a static class with a public and a private method ?

Comment: Because I can't see the point of creating an object just to use one method which would make more sense as a simple function . Perhaps I'm wrong but I think a class should be used to create objects that make some sense in themselves.